# Next Button Throwing an Error

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have a small script that paginates through several pages, clicks next until there are no more results. The code below clicks "next" until the button isn't displayed on the last page. For some reason I cannot stop it from throwing an error. I would like the script to continue if it doesn't find the "next" button.

```
myelement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='js-page-content']/div/main/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/div/ul/li[6]/a")

if myelement.is_displayed():
    myelement.click()
else:
    continue
```

Should I use "continue", "pass" or what? I've also tried the following code and it also errors out.

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='js-page-content']/div/main/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/div/ul/li[6]/a").click()
    time.sleep(5)
except NoSuchElementException:
    break
```

Comment: can you provide the html for //*[@id='js-page-content']/div/main/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/div/ul/li[6]/a , we may give you optimum solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The below code works.

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='js-page-content']/div/main/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/div/ul/li[6]/a").click()
    time.sleep(5)
except:
    break
```